# How can I programatically truncate order "O" terms in Maple?

Tags: maple

In Maple, `taylor(exp(x),x,2);` returns 1+*x*+O(*x*<sup>2</sup>).  How can I automatically convert this result to the same expression with the O(*x*<sup>2</sup>) terms removed?  I.e. something like `removeBigO(taylor(exp(x),x,2));` to return *1+x*?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
P := taylor(exp(x),x,2);

convert(P, polynom);
```

That conversion has its own [help-page](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=convert/polynom).

Note also that the help page for [taylor,details](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=taylor/details) has such a conversion as its last example. And the help page for [taylor](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=taylor) mentions that conversion of a Taylor series result to a polynomial is described on that details page.

Comment: I looked through the convert help-page but somehow I missed it (on the convert help page, the convert/polynom example is still there, but further down than on the page you linked). Thanks!